# Ionic - Firebase (How to get last record from database while updating database)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, observable, subscribe

Hello and thank you in advance for helping.
I am building a bus tracking ionic application. I am using firebase to store the location of the bus. Every few seconds, I store new coordinates to the database.

To view the current location of the bus, I retrieve the last recorded coordinates in the database. For some reason, if I simultaneously update the database and retrieve the last record from the database I get the error below. I suspect the error is as a result of a change in what is the last record while a user is requesting for the last record. Please how can I retrieve the last record in a manner that doesn't require that I subscribe to the result.

My code:

```
getLastLocation(){
return this.db.list<GPS>(this.baseURL,ref => ref.limitToLast(1)).valueChanges();
```

}

```
    getSpecific(){
this.firebaseService.getLastLocation()
.subscribe((resp)=>{
      this.buslon = resp[0].longitude;
      this.buslat= resp[0].latitude;
},
(err)=>{
  console.log(err);
})
}
```

My error:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'longitude' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber._next (driverstops.ts:54)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber._next (distinctUntilChanged.js:103)
at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (switchMap.js:124)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should find the reason why and when resp[0] is undefined.
And if you suspect that simultaneously updating situations, this doc would be helpful for you : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions